# Can Bootstrap responsive cancel some style when a site viewed via mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

#### CSS

```
.image {
     height:50px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class='span6'>
   <img class='image' />
</div>
<div class='span6'>
   <img class='image' />
</div>
```

Is it possible to cancel the style when the Bootstrap's responsive works?
I need these image to be displayed without crop by CSS, assuming that the picture's height is 400px.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the images with a maximum width that you wish them to be able to go. Preferably in percentage so that it scales on all devices.

Then add the class="img-responsive" to your image tags.

For example

```
<img src="/path/to/your/image/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Something about the image">
```

Comment: Note that the `img-responsive` class is only available in Bootstrap 3. You could also add `width: 100%` and `height: auto` to the img element for the same effect.